# Codename one how to make a multiple selector

Tags: user-interface, codenameone

Am trying to look around on how to make **multiple Selector**  for my app but I haven't found a solution about this in codename one.
This is what I want to achieve, something like that if anyone has an idea pliz.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We don't have that component but it should be relatively easy to implement. Just show a popup similarly to the code in this post: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-dont-use-combobox.html

On selection instead of setting text on a button just add buttons to a container with an X icon.

You can also use a checkbox list see this: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/button-lists.html